# iOS 13 Safari Mobile - IndexedDB - AbortError - The Operation Was Aborted

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, indexeddb, gwt-elemental

Since upgrading to iOS 13.1.2, Mobile Safari (through Cordova as well) seems to dislike my implementation of IndexedDB. I'm specifically getting the error of "AbortError: The operation was aborted" when attempting to either open the IndexedDB or executing onupgradeneeded. Everything seems to work fine on iOS 12. So was there an update to Mobile Safari's IndexedDB implementation in the latest rounds of updates? I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

I confirmed that it's failing on this line of code:

```
IDBDatabase db = (IDBDatabase) openDbRequest.result;
```

UPDATE 10/10/19 8:30 AM ET: I confirmed the issue also exists with Google Chrome installed on a iOS 13.1.2 device. I found [here](https://dexie.org/docs/IndexedDB-on-Safari) that "Due to Apples restricted policies for iOS, Chrome and Opera running on iOS is actually a Safari browser in the backend pretending to be Chrome or Opera. Thus, it’s IndexedDB is actually provided by Safari even on Chrome, Opera or Firefox"

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed my issue was with Google's Elemental2. I opened a bug with that particular project.

https://github.com/google/elemental2/